# Span up when mouse is on button

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to do this: when the mouse is on the button, the span's bottom-padding must increase. 
This is my button:

```
<button class="btn btn-success btn-circle" id="myBtn" title="Go to top">
    <span id="move" class="fa fa-chevron-up"></span></button>
```

I have tried to add a class, with bottom-padding bigger than the default(3px), with js.

My class:

```
.set {
        padding-bottom:13px;
    }
```

and this is my js:

```
window.onload = function() {
        document.getElementById("myBtn").onmouseover = function() {
            document.getElementById("myBtn").classList.add(" set");
        }
    }
```

but it doesn't work for me.
Can you help me? (i must do that when the mouse is no longer on button, the span's bottom-padding come back at 3px too) Thank you.

Comment: I think you look for the event `onmouseout`

Comment: if any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark and upvote. 
This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. 
There is no obligation to do this. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply do it with css:

```
.btn-circle:hover span{
 padding-bottom:13px;
}
```

**Explain**

```
 :hover // when mouseenter to elment
```

You have to do it `padding-bottom:13px;` instead of `padding-bottom=13px;`

Comment: I must move the span of button, not the button.

Answer (score 0):

Remove space in your class assignment `" set"` should be `"set"`. You can also set `document.getElementById("myBtn")` in a variable say `elem` so that you do not need to repeat the get element again from DOM.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var elem = document.getElementById("myBtn");
  elem.onmouseover = function() {
    elem.classList.add("set");
  }
}
```

```css
.set {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<button class="btn btn-success btn-circle" id="myBtn" title="Go to top">
<span id="move" class="fa fa-chevron-up">someIcon</span></button>
```

Comment: ` padding-bottom=13px;` is invalid

Comment: @לבנימלכה I just followed the same code that OP had and resolved the class add error. That is why I took `color` css in that class.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution could be the usage of CSS3: https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_transition1.
Instead of manipulating the width, you have to change the padding-bottom value.

Answer (score 0):

Im not completely sure if i get it … i think you want to move the inner span upwards and not increase the padding of the button itself … so:

```
#myBtn:hover #move {
    position: relative;
    top: -3px; // or whatever you want
}
```

You could animate that like so:

```
#move {
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    transition: all ease-in-out 0.3s;
}   

#myBtn:hover #move {
    position: relative;
    top: -3px; // or whatever you want
}
```

PS: There are many answers here with `padding-bottom` like in your question. But `padding-bottom` will affect the parents size ... i think that is not what you want … so `top` in combination with `position: relative` seems much more robust.